# My RCA tablet has 110 V DC adapter, does it work in India?

Tags: india, electronic-items, power

My RCA-VIKING-PRO 10 inches is a 110 V based one.
Can I use it in India where the input is 220 V?

The adapter given is 110 V only and pins that go into the wall mounted power source are also different from the Indian sockets.

I am moving to India shortly, am I to a bond on the tablet here in USA?

Comment: Your charger will at best not work, and at worst catch fire if you plug it in to 220V. Don't do it. But most tablet chargers are fairly similar so if you can find one meant for 220V with the same connector (usually micro-USB), which gives out the same voltage (probably 5V) and can provide the same or higher current (measured in mA or A, where 1000mA = 1A) you'll be fine.

Comment: Even if the charger can work on 220V, for long term use it is better to buy one with a plug that fits.

Comment: Do check the back of your adapter before assuming it is 110V only. That would be unusual for a tablet.

Answer (score 3):

Almost all power-supplies made in the last 20 years are "switching" -- that is, they adapt to the voltage they are given.

For example, look at [this one](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61NX9EvXRBL._SL1500_.jpg), which is for the Viking.  See where it says `Input: 100-240AC`?  That means you are cool anywhere in the world.

You will need a Euro-plug adapter [like this one](http://www.target.com/p/travel-smart-3-pk-continental-adapter-plug-set/-/A-16346730) to make it actually fit in the socket, about $2.50.

Ignore the commenters muttering about "bursting into flames" or "buying a new charger".  I have traveled literally around the world with my tablet and a [universal adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000ES6KPM), no voltage converter, and never had a glitch.  Worst thing is, some countries, the spring mechanism isn't too reliable and the adapter sometimes falls out of the wall.  *Quel dommage!*

Comment: Absolutely. I have not seen a single-voltage computer component since some cheap printers circa 1998. There is *zero* chance that this tablet needs a voltage transformer; it just needs to plug into the wall. I own a different model of universal adapter and it has worked everywhere. When I needed two, the hotel lent me one for their country.